# Searching multiple files for a string, without regular expressions?

Tags: find, utilities

Is there a command that can search multiple files for a string, where that command (perhaps modified by a certain option) doesn't support regular expressions? I'd like this for the speed of avoiding regular expressions, plus not having to escape special characters.

(It'd also be nice to know the options to recursively search within a directory and its subdirectories.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are text files and the string doesn't contain newline characters, you can use `grep` with the `-F` (for fixed-string) option.

```
string='any /text\ *string* without newline (\n).'
find . -type f -exec grep -F -l -e "$string" {} +
```

To list the text files that contain a line that contain that string.

(here restricting to *regular* files before symlink resolution)

Some `grep` implementations can also work with non-text files (like those contain NUL, bytes, with overlong lines, or sequences of bytes nor forming valid characters in your locale). Some can also do `find`'s job with a `-r`, `-R`, `-d recurse` option though there are some variation in behaviour when it comes to non-regular files or whether symlinks to directories are being followed when descending the directory tree.

With the `busybox` implementation of `grep`, you can make it work with strings of text containing newline characters with the `-z` option. `-z` is to work with NUL-delimited records instead of lines, but text files by definition cannot contain NULs and anyway you can't pass a NUL in an argument to a command or (except in `zsh`) store them in a shell variable such as `$string`.

So:

```
string='1
2
3'
busybox grep -raFlze "$string" .
```

Would work for arbitrary strings on any input. However note that `busybox grep -r` (at least current versions), look in files of any type, including symlinks, devices... so you may want to use `find` instead of its `-r` to restrict to *regular* files only:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -aFlze "$string" {} +
```

(some `find` implementations also have a `-xtype f` to check the type of file *after* symlink resolution to also search inside symlinks to regular files).

If the input files don't contain NUL bytes, that means that each file ends up being loaded whole in memory, so it doesn't scale well to very large files.

For arbitrary data containing possibly NULs and files of any size, you could store the string to search in a file and use `mmap()` to avoid loading files full in memory. With `perl` you could do something like:

```
needle_file=needle.bin # containing the string to search
size=$(wc -c < "$needle_file")

find . -type f -size "+$(( size - 1 ))c" -exec perl -MSys::Mmap -le '
  $needle = shift;
  open NEEDLE, "<", $needle or die "$needle: $!\n";
  mmap($needle, 0, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, NEEDLE);
  for (@ARGV) {
    if (open HAYSTACK, "<", $_) {
      mmap($haystack, 0, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, HAYSTACK);
      print if index($haystack, $needle) >= 0
    } else {
      warn "$_: $!\n"
    }
  }' -- "$needle_file" {} +
```

(note that `Sys::Mmap` is not one of `perl`'s core modules, you may have to install it like from a  `libsys-mmap-perl` package on Debian).

I can't tell how efficient `perl`'s `index()` substring search algorithm is at finding substrings.

`zsh` can store NULs in its variables, and can map the contents of files to variables, so you could do something like:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
set +o multibyte
string=$'foo\nbar\0baz'
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND.L+$(($#string - 1))e['[[ $mapfile[$REPLY] = *$string* ]]'])
```

But note that though `zsh` does use `mmap()` underneath, it does also end up copying the file contents in memory, and it being a shell, I doubt it's been optimised to the same kind of extent as a programming language such as `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
grep -inH -r "search_string" *
```

Comment: What about it? Could you describe why/how this solves the issue? Also, `grep` would treat the "string" as a regular expression, not as a string, so you may want to add `-F` to the mix of options used.  Also, if the search string starts with a dash, you will have to prefix it with `-e`.